# ACS Engine Azure VNET Integrarion

Tags: azure, kubernetes, containers, azure-aks

I have trouble integrating an ACS Engine Cluster with my existing VNET in Azure.
Below are the steps to reproduce my issue:

1. Create an ACS Engine Cluster with default configuration. It creates its own VNET(let's say ACS_VNET)
2. Create a new VNET(VNET2) with a VM and do a VNET Peering to ACS_VNET.
3. Create a sample service with Azure Private Load Balancer and try to access its private IP from the above VM in VNET2. It does not work. Also tried with Private IP of the pod and with a NodePort with no luck.

Followed this article to create the cluster: https://dzone.com/articles/create-custom-azure-kubernetes-clusters-with-acs-e

Above steps works for an AKS Cluster in Azure.

Comment: this probably depends on what network plugin you choose for your k8s cluster

Comment: I used the default azure network plugin. Does this work with any other network plugin?

Comment: the default should work. are those vnets in the same region? if they are not internal lb wont be accessible via peering

Comment: They are in the same region - central us.

Comment: are you sure lb works properly? can you use lb from inside the network? did you try node ip + port instead of pod ip + port?

Comment: i tested ilb with a jumpbox(a server inside the cluster VNET) and ILB works without any issue. Also the jumpbox server is able to ping the VM in VNET2 and vice versa. Its only the containers/ilb which are not discoverable outside their VNET with a peered VNET.

Comment: hm, maybe the issue is with the user defined route, maybe you need that on the second vnet as well

Comment: Any article explaining to update udr for the VNET?

Comment: its literally faster to google this than to ask to for it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/tutorial-create-route-table-portal

Comment: my issue is not with creating a route table. ASAIK Vnet Peering does not need any route table and as i mentioned above, aks setup works for the vnet peering scenario.

Comment: do you have nsg\azure firewall in the picture? and that article also shows how to attach the udr (i guess you didnt read it)

Comment: Both kubenet and Azure CNI do not need any route table update. As mentioned above, i tried all the steps mentioned on Azure Documentation and did not miss any steps. Looking for someone who has deployed it successfully.

Comment: thats not true, both acs and aks require udrs. I'm looking at the existing aks cluster on my subscription, it has UDR, what it does it routes all the requests to the ephemeral k8s virtual network through the worker nodes. this cluster was created with the default networking - so azure

Comment: its true for aks but acs engine says there is no requirement for udr for Azure CNI and kubenet!

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/acs-engine/blob/master/docs/kubernetes/features.md#kubenet-networking-custom-vnet this claims that you need udr for kubenet at least. you might also need that for Azure CNI (pretty sure you do). it just says that if you are using kubenet you need some manual configs. that might be automated with Azure CNI. I think you need to read more about what you are doing

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to redeploy it with proper udr to see if it works.